# Facebook Session is null

Tags: c#, session, webforms, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK V6 and am using this tutorial.

http://csharpsdk.org/docs/web/getting-started

I have got nearly everything working - however every time I try to assign my Access Token to my context.Session["AccessToken"] I receive a null exception.

Here is the bit of code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var accessToken = context.Request["accessToken"];
        context.Session["AccessToken"] = accessToken;

        context.Response.Redirect("/Facebook.aspx");
    }
```

It errors on line 2 - during debug I can see the Session is null as it comes into the handler.

I am using webforms for this example.

Any help would be great.

Owen

Comment: I solved it!

My Generic Handler needed to be declared:

    public class FacebookLogin : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
    

Thanks to any one who looked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs have now been updated with the fix.

```
public class FacebookLogin : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
```

inherit from `IRequiresSessionState` so you can access the session.